# How to set special price for specific customer group Programmatically

Tags: php, magento2.4, magento2.4.3, magento2.4.3.p1

Guys I'm wondering how to add a special price for a specific customer group? For example, I have a group called "Special Customers", I want to set 10% price increase on every product for this specified group only. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I thin you can use group pricing. take a look at this
https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/product-price-group.html

You can use the configuration settings in the Admin to set prices for discounted items based on customer groups in your store. This is called group pricing.

Comment: I've answered, let's have a check on it too.If its working then accept it too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you create di.xml for plugin

> etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
        <plugin name="change_product" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Product"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

and then create a plugin for it

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/Product.php

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;

/**
 * class for changing product price
 */
class Product
{
    protected Session $customersession;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject
     * @param $result
     * @return int
     */
    public function __construct(
        Session $customerSession
    ){
        $this->customersession = $customerSession;

    }
    public function afterGetPrice(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject,
                                       $result
    ) {
    $customerGroup=$this->customersession->getCustomer()->getGroupId();
    if($customerGroup == 4){
        return $result * 1.2;
    }
    return $result;
    }
}
```

Mine customer group id is 4 like this `$customerGroup == 4` in your case you have to check yours first and then try it.

Comment: I've answered, let's have a check on it too.If it's working then accept it too

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php

namespace Test\Sample\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductTierPriceManagementInterface;

class Index extends Action
{

    protected $tierPrice;

    public function __construct(Context $context, ProductTierPriceManagementInterface $tier)
    {
        $this->tierPrice = $tier;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

     public function execute()
    {
        $sku = 'test-sku'; //Product sku
        $customerGroupId = 2; //Wholsaler group id
        $price = 200;
        $qty = 55;

        $this->tierPrice->add($sku,$customerGroupId,$price, $qty);
    }
}
```

Comment: How to use this on the products category page? e.x in list.phtml file.

Comment: Very Simple, Just create the object of $this->tierPrice using the block or use directly OM, and then pass the required details like sku, customergpId, price and qty.
For Reference use how to override it : https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/how-to-override-template-phtml-files-in-magento-2/